# Turing machines with a finite number of states

Tags: automata

In a class on Turing machines, the lecturer said that the language for a machine with 100 states is both recognizable and decidable.

How can we infer this just from the number of states in the machine?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, but as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion.  We expect you to make a significant effort before asking and to show us what you've tried.  (P.S. Your question needed significant editing.  Please take more care with the question and title in the future.  Thank you!)

Comment: all TMs have a finite # of states

Comment: As you formulate it it is not clear what the lecturer meant to say. Was this a claim about a particular Turing machine with 100 states, or a claim about *all* Turing machines with 100 states? Was it a claim about the language *accepted* by the Turing machine, or the language that *describes* the machine using some specific notation?

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood your lecturer's claim. Their claim was that the language of *descriptions* of Turing machines with 100 states is decidable. The language *accepted* by each such machine need not be.

In other words, given a string, you can decide whether it describes a Turing machine having 100 states. That's the extent of the claim.